# How can I sort by multiple columns but not by value?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Question title might be a bit vague, so feel free to change it into something that makes more sense, I just couldn't find the right words.

So here is my problem:

In my table there are 2 important columns

- date_added (a datetime value)
- special_price (numeric)

special_price is either `NULL` or a numeric value depending on what the special price is.

I'll describe the way I want to order my result now:

First I want to see all the items with no special_price (`NULL`) ordered by date (newest first), Then I want to see the items that do have a special_price (so anything other than `NULL`) ordered by date.

At first I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY special_price, date_added DESC
```

This worked great for the first part where all the special_price values where `NULL`, but when it started with the the items that did have a special_price ordered on the value that was in the special_price column. This makes sense of course because in the query I wanted to order by special_price first.

So how can I let the query ignore the value of special_price and just see whether it's `NULL` or not? So I get all `NULL`'s ordered by date and then I get all the `NOT NULL`'s ordered by date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF( ISNULL( special_price ), 0, 1 ), date_added DESC
```

Comment: Nice and simple, a single SELECT +1

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed! I would never had figured this out myself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

`SELECT *, IF(special_price IS NULL, 0, 1) AS orderer FROM products ORDER BY orderer, date_added DESC`

that works fine for what you want to accomplish

Comment: Won't the special price show either 0 or 1? because it has to be either NULL/0 or a numeric value like 49.99 or 10.

Comment: No, special_price remains unchanged is the orderer that takes value 0 if special_price is null and 1 if it has a value.