# MySQL: order by two columns with NULLs last?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I know there are similiar questions on SO, but unfortunately I haven't found the answer to mine, so asking here.

My result table structure looks like this:

```
id    item_id   price    group
-------------------------------
1     3472      NULL      
2     234       300      1
3     4872      150      1
4     1109      100
5     5582      300      0
6     144       150      2
7     1384      NULL     1
8     627       100      2
```

`price` column can have NULLs and `group` column can have empty results.

The table is sortable by price.

What I need is:

1. Order the result set by two columns - **price** and **group**
2. Results with the same `price` have to be ordererd according to their
   groups first (ascending), results with the same price but without group go after them.
3. NULLs always have to be last regardless of `price` sort order (DESC
   or ASC).

So, the table with ordering should look like this:

```
id    item_id   price    group
-------------------------------
8     627       100      2
4     1109      100
3     4872      150      1
6     144       150      2
5     5582      300      0
2     234       300      1
7     1384      NULL     1
1     3472      NULL
```

When I need to order with NULLs last I use something like:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(column), column
```

And ordering by multiple columns usually is not a problem, but I just stuck with this one.  I've spent a few hours with no results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort by multiple columns but not by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857110/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-columns-but-not-by-value), just change the return for true to something larger then could occur on price.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that group column can have empty results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF( ISNULL( price ), 1, 0 ), price, IF( group='', 1, 0 ), group ASC
```

Comment: As a corollary, if you wanted to order only by values higher than a certain value, e.g zero: `... ORDER BY col > 0 DESC, col ASC`